# How can I flatten nn.Embedding in nn.Sequential?

Tags: pytorch

As an exercise, I was trying to rewrite the basic embedding tutorial for PyTorch as an `nn.Sequential`: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/word_embeddings_tutorial.html

```py
class NGramLanguageModeler(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, context_size):
        super(NGramLanguageModeler, self).__init__()
        self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(context_size * embedding_dim, 128)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(128, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        embeds = self.embeddings(inputs).view((1, -1))
        out = F.relu(self.linear1(embeds))
        out = self.linear2(out)
        log_probs = F.log_softmax(out, dim=1)
        return log_probs
```

I think this should be something like this:

```py
nn.Sequential(
   nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, device=device),
   nn.Flatten(1, -1),
   nn.Linear(context_size * embedding_dim, 128, device=device),
   nn.ReLU(), # first
   nn.Linear(128, vocab_size, device=device),
   nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
)
```

However, after Flatten, I have a dimensionality mismatch. I do not produce a `1 x context_size * embedding_dim` matrix and instead a `context_size x embedding_dim` matrix. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the equivalent...

```py
nn.Sequential(
  nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, device=device),
  nn.Flatten(0),
  nn.Linear(context_size * embedding_dim, 128, device=device),
  nn.ReLU(), # first
  nn.Linear(128, vocab_size, device=device),
  nn.LogSoftmax(0),
  nn.Unflatten(0, (1, vocab_size))
)
```